# Remove single quote and escaping characters from a string

Tags: python, postgresql

I have an SQL query:

```
"INSERT INTO table ('id', 'name', 'age_of_use') VALUES (1, 'someone', 33)"
```

or

```
'INSERT INTO table ("id", "name", 'age_of_use') VALUES (1, 'someone', 33)'
```

I would like to turn it into

```
"INSERT INTO table (id, name, age_of_use) VALUES (1, 'someone', 33)"
```

I have tried regex and repr() and the best I got is to:

```
"INSERT INTO table (\'id\', \'name\',\'age_of_use\') VALUES (1, \'someone\', 33)"
```

(I am aware of SQL injection)

Comment: You need a parser for you particular dialect of SQL and a code generator for the resulting AST. I wouldn't trust the result of anything more ad hoc.

Comment: Why and what are you going to do with the query?  Using [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) you could do `cur.execute("INSERT INTO table ('id', 'name', 'age_of_use') VALUES (1, 'someone', 33)")`.  Or pass in parameters using [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) or build the query using [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).